# EC2 Linux Instance PHPInfo doesnt show mysql

Tags: php, mysql, linux, amazon-ec2

I have just created a Linux instance on aws, php/apache/mysql are all installed and they are all running yet when i browse to my instance URL with just phpinfo in the index.php, the MySQL section of the info doesn't show up. I have tried restarting the web server and making sure everything is running and installed. Ideas?

Comment: Have you made sure the appropriate PHP mysql (PDO for example) package has been installed?

Comment: What did you use to install them in the first place? Also, are we talking mod_php, or PHP-FPM?

Comment: im assuming that when i try and install the packages and get conflict errors that this must mean they are already installed, is this correct? Also, i can try installing one at a time and seeing what happens.

Comment: Are you able to connect to the database using a database client? Verify that  your database is up and running.

Comment: yes i can connect to the database through workbench and also connect via command line

Comment: it looks like i was missing package php56-mysqlnd, i have now installed this and restarted mysql as well as apache. Let see if this works.

Answer (score 0):

Try from console:

```
# php -m | grep mysql
mysql
mysqli
mysqlnd
pdo_mysql
```

If you do not see the extensions, it means they're not installed. What exactly you need depends on desired version, in my case there are some options:

```
# yum search php | grep -i mysql
php-mysql.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that use MySQL databases
php-mysqlnd.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that use MySQL databases
php54-mysql.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that use MySQL databases
php54-mysqlnd.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that use MySQL databases
php55-mysqlnd.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that use MySQL databases
php56-mysqlnd.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that use MySQL databases
```

so you'll need to run `yum install php-...whatever-you-need..`

Don't forget to `apachectl graceful` after that.

If modules are installed then php from apache is not the same (or at least uses not the same config) as php from the command line. Look for difference with `php -i`.